# window.open not working when attached on onload event in chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, safari, google-chrome, window, cross-browser

I want to open a new window on onload if a particular condition is satisfied works fine in all others but window is not opening in Chrome and Safari would somebody please find a way to do this

**Duplicate:** [window.open not working when attached on onload event in chrome and safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724355/window-open-not-working-when-attached-on-onload-event-in-chrome-and-safari)

Answer (score 2):

Both Safari and Chrome does by default block popups opened on load. You may turn off popup-blocking in the preferences, or you could try going with a modal window.

Comment: Modal window dosen't work too...

Comment: Umm… perhaps JavaScript is off?