# window.open from PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, window.open

Ok, I want to open a new window from inside of a PHP script so I am just echo-ing JS as such:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('".configController::$BASE_URL."/view/share.php?u=".$url."');</script>";
```

I just want a normal window to open that the user can interact with, however ... I get a sickly gazzelle looking window with no menubar, status, etc. It's a pure pop-up ( icky ).

I've tried supplying the open preferences and enabling all the options, but I still get that featureless window.

Here is the PHP with the options enabled:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('".configController::$BASE_URL."/view/share.php?u=".$url."',' Share','toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes');</script>";
```

and here is the JS it generates:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.open('http://localhost:8888/lks/view/share.php?u=www.yahoo.com',' Share','toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes');
</script>
```

If I use window.open('url here') from a button click that will do what I want ... What's the difference? and ... How can I open just a plain window ?

**EDIT:**

Diving deeper .... I put this page together. The onLoad event will open the lame-o window... clicking the Click Me opens the window properly.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function popit(){
            //window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','_blank');
            window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','Share','toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,history=yes,resizable=yes');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="popit()">
    <a href="#" onclick="popit();">CLICK ME</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Found this, I'm guessing the browser is acting weird because a bunch of people in the 1990s decided to abuse JS... The idea was to not interrupt the users experience while sharing, but it looks like I'll have to use the same window and redirect back to the original url when they're done.

[window.open not working when attached on onload event in chrome and safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724484/window-open-not-working-when-attached-on-onload-event-in-chrome-and-safari)

**EDIT 3:**
Years later I must clarify that this was not a duplicate question. The original ask was about a window.open from a backend script, at the time that was PHP. When you mark something as a duplicate consider that you're dropping the hammer on the entire subject matter. Just because I link to another S/O answer, that doesn't mean you can throw away the rest of the material.

Answer (score -1):

Third parameter to `window.open`. Did you try `"toolbar=yes, location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes"`?

Comment: I tried both "toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes" as well as "status=1,toolbar=1,location=1,menubar=1,directories=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1"

Comment: Are you sure you put it as the *third* parameter? Would you mind posting the exact code you used? Your code example does not show any window options being used.

Comment: Ok, here is the script with options:
------->
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('".configController::$BASE_URL."/view/share.php?u=".$url."','lks.im Share','toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes');</script>";

and here is what it generates:
----->>>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.open('http://localhost:8888/lks/view/share.php?u=www.yahoo.com','lks.im Share','toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes');
</script>

Comment: @kroolk , please edit your question to include that code.  As it stands, it is unreadable in your comment.

Comment: Here's a nice site with a working example under "A New Browser Window": http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm

Answer (score -1):

How bout something simple like I used this in a handful of places, works with chrome, firefox, ie, safari, opera.. recently used this in a project I am working on. So it still appears to work.

`window.open(url, "_blank");`