# popup window not opening in chrome and firefox but opens in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

i have been trying to open a popup window from one page on button click which is opened using Javascript from another application.

code:

```
Dim script As String = "window.open('login.aspx','','status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=1,maximize=1,modal=yes,scrollbars=yes');"
script &= "window.opener = 'Self';window.open('','_parent',''); window.close();"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "", script, True)
```

this code works fine with IE it opens popup window but does not works with chrome and Firefox.

and also when i directly accessing that application url code works fine with all the browsers but when accessing it through another application it creates problem.

Comment: Relying on such popup windows is not recommended. Almost all browsers/adblockers/virusscan plugins block those.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724355/window-open-not-working-when-attached-on-onload-event-in-chrome-and-safari

Comment: when i removed that window.close(); code it works fine on Chrome and IE but Mozilla still doesn't work.